# I have a problem when using "export" command

Tags: environment-variables

When I put sudo "export PROXY_LOCAL_NET_IP=10.113.35.108" I get the following error:

```
sudo: export: command not found
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does it work without sudo?

Comment: Probably you shouldn't use quotes in command.

Comment: export won't work with fish-bash for whatever reason

Comment: How to keep environment variables when using sudo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use shell builtins with `sudo`. Only command corresponding to valid files will be executed through `sudo`. The correct syntax for sudo is : `sudo [options] [filename]`

Export is an inside (builtin) command of the Bash shell and possibly some other too.

Also, note that there is no sense to do the action of `export` via `sudo`, it has to be done under your user id to be applicable to your shell and its child processes.

If you switch to the root user to do this, you will have to do the rest of your operation as root : **this is not recommended**. Because if you exit the root shell, the assignement done by `export` will be lost.

Answer (score 8):

Become root user with `sudo -s` and your password.
Then enter your command without sudo:export PROXY_LOCAL_NET_IP=10.113.35.108`

Answer (score 8):

You can use
    sudo -E 
option to use exported variable in a sudo command

The following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo) has some additional details on how to use  environment variable with sudo